# KendoUI Template with Observable with NumericTextbox

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-template, kendonumerictextbox, kendo-observable

I have the following KendoUI template bound to an observable.  When I push a new item to the observable array, how do I apply the kendoNumericTextBox to only the new item in the template?

If I apply by class, it has a strange effect of doubling the spinners on the existing numeric textboxes.

```
<div id="slots">
        <table class="table table-striped table-condensed" style="width:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Volunteers Needed</th>
                    <th>
                        Reservation Passcode <i class="icon-question-sign" title ="Only people with the reservation passcode can signup."></i>
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: slots">
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </div>



 $(document).ready(function () {
          var viewModel = kendo.observable({
                slots: [{DateText:'1/8/1969', ShiftLabel: "3:00 to 5:00",Slots:2,ReservationCode:"ABC" }]
              });
          kendo.bind($("#slots"), viewModel);
          $(".numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
              format: "n0"
          });

          viewModel.slots.push({DateText:'1/8/1969', ShiftLabel: "3:00 to 5:00",Slots:2,ReservationCode:"ABC" });

          $(".numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
              format: "n0"
          });  
 });
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining your template as:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-tmpl" id="row-template">
    <tr>
        <td>#= DateText #</td>
        <td>#= ShiftLabel #</td>
        <td class="numeric"><input data-role="numerictextbox" data-format="n0" data-bind="value: Slots"></td>
        <td>#= ReservationCode #</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

and remove the `$(".numeric").kendoNumericTextBox(...)` initializations. Doing this you should have a `NumericTextBox` each time the template is run (one per row).

Your JavaScript is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({
        slots: [
            {DateText: '1/8/1969', ShiftLabel: "3:00 to 5:00", Slots: 2, ReservationCode: "ABC" }
        ]
    });
    kendo.bind($("#slots"), viewModel);

    viewModel.slots.push({DateText: '1/8/1969', ShiftLabel: "3:00 to 5:00", Slots: 3, ReservationCode: "ABC" });
});
```

See it running here http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/BV48W/

**Why:**
The fact that you use a CSS class (`.numeric`) causes you end up having a KendoUI Numeric Text Box inside the other.

*Example*: You have the following HTML:

```
<label>Number 1: <input id="number1" class="numeric"/></label>
<label>Number 2: <input id="number2" class="numeric"/></label>
```

And the JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "n0"
    });
    $(".numeric").kendoNumericTextBox({
        format: "n0"
    });
});
```

You will see what you called *strange effect of doubling the spinners on the existing numeric textboxes*.

Each time that you invoke `kendoNumericTextBox` using `.numeric` selector you add one extra spinner to the element. If it does not have a spinner (data just added to `viewModel`) it gets one *but* if then you add data and invoke `kendoNumericTextBox` using `.numeric` selector, that previous element gets another.

Comment: Use `data-format="n0"` (I've updated the answer for including it).